# Modify javascript function while xajax execution

Tags: php, xajax

I want to create a javascript function within a xajax function(php) and assign it in response.

```
<?php
    require_once("Resources/xajax/xajax_core/xajax.inc.php");
    $xajax = new xajax(); 

    function foo()
    {
       $response = new xajaxResponse();
       // The code needed should be here...
          // Here create the javascript sintax using php and put it on the web
              // No problem creating the sintax but
                 ->// how I put it on a new <script></script> ????
          // Here call the javascript
          $response->script('myJavascript');

       return $response

    }

    $xajax->configure( 'javascript URI', 'Resources/xajax/');
    $xajax->register(XAJAX_FUNCTION,"foo");
    $xajax->processRequest();
?>

    <html>.......

    <button onclick="xajax_foo()"></button>
    ......</html>
```

Don't know if I'm being clear but in short I want is that before running xajax there's no javascript and then there's a javascript and it's running. Maybe I should use two xajax responses, one to put the script into the web and another to call it... but at this point I need your help.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi guys, I found this: http://www.xajaxproject.org/en/docs-tutorials/api-docs/xajax-core/xajaxresponse-inc-php/xajaxresponse/setfunction/

setFunction($sFunction, $sArgs, $sScript)
Parameters:
sFunction (string) The name of the function to construct.
sArgs (string) Comma separated list of parameter names.
sScript (string) The javascript code that will become the body of the function.

Don't really know how to use it.. I did this but didn't work:
$sFunction = "test";
$sArgs = "";
$sScript = "alert('Test');";
$response->setFunction($sFunction, $sArgs, $sScript);
$response->script($sFunction);

Comment: Finally found a solution, see the post edit.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using this:

```
$response->call("javascriptfoo","param1","param2");
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Cropped from the question.](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12588359/5)**

---

I found a solution:

Include this in your PHP:

```
$response->call("javascriptfoo()","$param1","$param2"));
```

You need this in your HTML:

```
<script... > 
function javascriptfoo(param1,param2) {
    alert(param1);
    alert(param2);
}
</script>
```